# Using fsolve with scipy function

Tags: python, scipy

I have encountered the following problem with `scipy.fsolve`, but I don't what to do:

```
U = 0.00043
ThC =1.19
Dist = 7   
IncT = 0.2  
pcw = 1180000          
k = 1.19                    
B = U * pcw / (2 * k)

fugato = fsolve((((Ql/(2*math.pi* k))*math.exp(B * x)*special.kv(0, B * x))-IncT),0.01)

print fugato
```

I get the error `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable` in fsolve.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: The first argument of fsolve must be a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `fsolve` must be a function.

I presume that you want to solve your equation for `x`? If so, writing:

```
fugato = fsolve(lambda x: Ql/(2*math.pi* k)*math.exp(B * x)*special.kv(0, B * x)-IncT,
                0.01)
```

works.

---

To explain what's going on here, the construct `lambda x: 2*x` is a function definition. It is similar to writing:

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x
```

The `lambda` construction is commonly used to define functions that you only need once. This is often the case when registering callbacks, or to represent a mathematical expression. For instance, if you wanted to integrate `f(x) = 2*x`, you could write:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
integral = quad(lambda x: 2*x, 0., 3.)
```

Similarly, if you want to solve 2*x = 1, you can write:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
fsolve(lambda x: 2*x-1, 0.)
```